# pexpect to expect more than one pattern

Tags: python, pexpect

```
import pexpect # importing the python-expect
child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet x.x.x.x y')
child.expect ('Hit \[Enter\] to boot immediately\, or space bar for command prompt.', 300)
child.send ('\x20')
if child.expect ('loader>' or 'OK ', 10):
   child.sendline ('boot -s')
```

What I am trying to do here is:

- automating login to single user mode for a device by parsing boot sequence.
- Connecting to the device using a terminal server over the console port. $ I am using pexpect as the boot sequence is a single line output.
- pexpect work for 'loader>' or 'OK ' separately & execute the next line but not together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html):

> `expect(pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False)`
>
> > This seeks through the stream until a pattern is matched. The pattern is overloaded and may take several
> >     types. **The pattern can be a StringType, EOF, a compiled re, or a list of any of those types.** Strings will be
> >     compiled to re types. **This returns the index into the pattern list.** If the pattern was not a list this returns
> >     index 0 on a successful match.
> >     [...]